# scrapy same url different source content

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy on the following website in order to get soccer match URLs.
http://www.spox.com/de/daten/?sport=soccer&page=season&id=9643&view=matches

So far so good it takes all the URLs of the 25 matches shown but there is a "back" ("Zurück") button to show more matches but it uses the same URL. So how do I tell scrapy to press that button and also take that match URLs?

Answer (score 1):

The browser makes a `XMLHttpRequest` when the back button is pressed. I would suggest to fire up the console of your browser and inspect the network traffic after pressing the back button. You'll see the url from which the page is getting data. Use that url for further scraping.

Comment: Or use Splash (https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) to render the page and click the button. But reverse engineering, in this case, might be easier and faster.